# Suggest a Online repositories & project management tool for a project in Asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, svn, git

Our team doing a project in asp.net & Mssql 2005.since our team member are distributed. we need a online tool for tracking project changes, and control access to our online code repositories.

- While searching i got tools like
  http://codesion.com
  , http://repositoryhosting.com
- is project mangement possible using  http://codesion.com
  , http://repositoryhosting.com
- Suggest a better tools for the doing
  project.

Comment: If you want really a simple and sophisticated one. Go for https://www.spmlive.com
You can create project and add task to it. It has time tracker also. Just love this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.codespaces.com/ has some execelent project management, taks scheduling, bug tracking software combined with good source control of SVN or GIT. Using Tortoise SVN or Tortoise GIT.

Github and GoogleCode are great, but I think they both require an opensource project.

Comment: I'm using it for more than a year and it proved very stable and cheap. I'm on the cheapest plan that completely satisfies my needs.

Comment: And its gone! Domain for sale!

Answer (score 1):

Another question to answer is: **Do you need strict access control below repositories?**

In Subversion you can always undo each and every change a developer makes. So as long as you only allow your developers acces to the repository you can handle the rest of the security via policy.

This won't work in cases with external contracters, but if all developers are normal employees, in many cases there is no need to restrict access.

Im my eyes the time to configure every directory tree every time is much more costly than to fix a possible deletion/breakage later. (Giving access to a repository is uncommon; a new directory very common).

That leaves the tracking of changes; and I usually use [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.net/) and [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net) for that. (Easier to maintain than most web tools and very easy to install.. You probably have them already).

Then you only need some issue tracker...

Answer (score 0):

http://hosted-projects.com/ No downtime (noticed) in about a year. They provide the best project management tool I ever used: [trac](http://trac.edgewall.com).

Comment: hosted-projects.com is not longer offering hosted Trac.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across [Freepository](https://freepository.com/index.php) it uses SVN. Not set up a project on it yet though so don't know its pro's and con's.